# Is there a more succinct way of filtering an array based on a filter property?

Tags: javascript

I've got an array of sessions defined something like this:

```
const sessions = [{id: 1, eventYear: "2019"},{id: 2, eventYear: "2018"},{id: 3, eventYear: "2018"}];
```

and I want to create a new array of objects with just the eventYear "2018"

I tried mapping over the array and if `session.eventYear === eventYear` return the session record, otherwise return nothing, but got a list of objects 3 long (not 2) with one undefined record.  I wanted just 2 records returned.

I have the following working, but it feels uncomfortably non functional and long.  I'd appreciate a suggestion for how to make this more concise in modern JavaScript

```
const sessionsForEventYear = [];
sessions.map(function(session) {
  if (session.eventYear === eventYear) {
    sessionsForEventYear.push(session);
  }
});
```

Comment: If you're not interested in the return value of `.map()` you shouldn't be using it. In this case you should use `.forEach()` or `.reduce()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.prototype.filter` instead:

```js
const sessions = [{id: 1, eventYear: "2019"},{id: 2, eventYear: "2018"},{id: 3, eventYear: "2018"}];
const sessionsForEventYear = sessions.filter(({ eventYear }) => eventYear === '2018');
console.log(sessionsForEventYear);
```

Comment: Does filter create a new object or does it carry references to the old one?

Comment: The *array* is new, but the items of the prior array are not copied - the new array holds references to the same objects.

Comment: Is map the same as filter in that regard.  Thanks! I did not realize that subtlety.

Comment: Also, I looked at the other question this was closed in favor of, and I did not see any discussion around what is returned (that is, referrence or new objects).  Seems to me that makes it a non-dupe.